# How can I capture network request made internally from Chrome

Tags: networking, google-chrome, wireshark

Chrome can autofill credit card information based on saved credit cards in Google Pay. As far as I know, when the Chrome alert asks you for the CVC of the credit card it sends a request to google after you submit and then returns the name of the cardholder, credit card number, expiration date, and CVC.

[Link to Google website about autofill](https://www.google.com/chrome/privacy/whitepaper.html#autofill)

I would like to make the same request from my own software so I don't need to directly store my credit card information in my program but I can't find out what the request looks like. I'm not even sure if it is even possible to imitate the request or if it is only possible from Chrome itself.

I have already tried to use Wireshark to look at all the network traffic but i can't seem to find anything related to that specific request. I am not at all experienced with any traffic analyzing software so I might just have overseen it.

Comment: You could use Network Monitor to capture the network trace. For more details, please refer to this article: [Collect data using Network Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-netmon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you've not seen it as it would certainly be encrypted. You'll have to store your browser's key and feed it to Wireshark for decryption.

See [this](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS?action=show&redirect=SSL#TLS_Decryption) for Wireshark decryption. It's deprecated, but should give you an idea of how to log TLS keys the browser uses and the decryption setup in Wireshark.

Note that it may take you a while before you learn Wireshark, as it's quite complex. I can recommend [this](https://nostarch.com/packetanalysis3) book for learning.

Comment: Could you shortly explain how I would do that, or link me to an article?

Comment: @LukasGruber See update.

Comment: Ok, so apparently I have just overlooked it.
The requests when submitting the alert are in the QUIC protocol.
Sadly I have never heard about that before and the traffic is of course encrypted.
Do you know by any chance how I can decrypt that data?
I will accept your answer as it helped me get on with my problem

Comment: @LukasGruber Search on the net, see this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63290913/wireshark-doesnt-show-quic-protocol With TLS decryption, remember about sefty when handling keys. You don't want them to go public for real sessions - any of them.